# Connect sensors to the raspberry pi using the inbuilt wifi

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, wifi

I am able to connect sensors using the GPIO pins.

**My Question is:**

Is there any possible way to connect any kind of sensors to the raspberry pi via Bluetooth or wifi?

And get the data via the same!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with *any kind of sensors*. I should be:

***Sensor*** -> Micro-Controller <- Bluetooth/Wifi Module  )))))))))))((((((((((( *Bluetooth/Wifi Module -> **Raspberry Pi***